# how to retrieve data that contains special characters including alphabet

Tags: sql, special-characters, hiveql, sql-like, regexp-like

I'm using oracle and hive db engine and supposed that in a varchar column (phone number), I only want to retrieve record with digit and hyphen '-'
i.e. 03-1234 5678

But how if I want to retrieve if column has special chars (except hyphen) and alphabet using like or rlike.

i.e 03-ABC123$#45XYZ or 03-AB123 Y123#& (with space)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've asked for two different things here.  What type of phone numbers do you actually want to match?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen. I want to only retrieve phone number with number and hyphen (03-12345 6789) only. Others should be invalid. but also if I want to do rlike, what is the reverse operation for it..

Answer (score 0):

Using `RLIKE` we can try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE phone RLIKE '^[0-9 -]+$';
```

This will match only phone numbers consisting of digits, space, or hyphen.

Comment: Thanks Tim! it works. but can you explain what do + and $ define here?

Comment: The pattern says to match from the start `^` any digit, hyphen, or space character, one or more times `+`, until the end `$`.